# How to set different type of edges in Sigma.js?

Tags: graph, sigma.js

How can we set Different type of edges in Sigma.js? I want to set different types of edges (solid, dashed, dotted, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question can be found in the Sigma.js source code. If you look at sigma.js-[version-num]/examples/plugin-customEdgeShapes.html it shows you how to set the type property of an edge when you create it.

```
g.edges.push({
    id: 'e' + i,
    source: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
    target: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
    type: [
      'line',
      'curve',
      'arrow',
      'curvedArrow',
      'dashed',
      'dotted',
      'parallel',
      'tapered'
    ][Math.round(Math.random()*8)],
    size: Math.random()
  });
```

They randomly select a type in their code but you can define any of those types to get the desired style. (Open up the plugin-customEdgeShapes.html in a browser to get a quick view of what the styles look like.)